# How to test if an object is a formula in base R?

Tags: r

R has many helpers for testing object type, e.g. `is.character(x)`

Is there an equivalent for the (strangely missing) `is.formula(x)`?

(PS: I see that at least one package has implemented this outside base R)

Comment: Well, `as.formula` just returns it's argument when `interits(x,"formula")` is TRUE, so you just just use that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From my comment, you could just do:

```
is.formula <- function(x){
   inherits(x,"formula")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `rlang::is_formula()` or `rlang::is_bare_formula()` from *rlang*'s doc :

> `is_formula()` tests if `x` is a call to `~`. `is_bare_formula()` tests in addition that `x` does not inherit from anything else than "formula".

`inherits()` is a common approach but if we want to be rigorous we should look at the call, not the class attribute, as `rlang::is_formula()` does, I propose a base version here :

```r
a_formula <- ~foo
not_a_formula <- "foo"
class(not_a_formula) <- "formula"

inherits(a_formula, "formula")
#> [1] TRUE
inherits(not_a_formula, "formula")
#> [1] TRUE

is.formula <- function(x) is.call(x) && x[[1]] == quote(`~`)
is.formula(a_formula)
#> [1] TRUE
is.formula(not_a_formula)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>